# how to display the items in the combobox in any given manner?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a dropdown getting populated by fetching a query on the database.
Say it fetches items given as follows:

Teacher,
Student,
Pricipal,
Sweeper,
FinanceManager.

While showing it in the dropdown, I wish to show it in the following order:

Principal,
FinanceManager,
Teacher,
Student,
Sweeper.

This isn't any specific order (ascending or descending), but just a order that has some relevance according to the personalities.

How do I acheive  ?

Comment: Does this order have any kind of reference? Like do you have a table which is contains orders? or any other logic to pivot the sort?

Comment: Which language is the combobox? c#? js? asp?

Comment: please provide some more details about the data object/format

Comment: No, the table does not contain any such column that will set the priority for these items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you fetching the data from database,the easy solution to me is adding a extra column to the same table which hold order.

```
eg. Your Table
    Column1 Column2 .... DisplayOrder(int)
    Principal                     1
    FinanceManager                2
    etc...
```

So you can order by the DisplayOrder when you do the selection

Answer (score 3):

you could give them an extra "role-flag" in your db

```
ID NAME       FLAG
1  Principal  5
3  FinanceM   4
33 Teacher    3
22 Student    2
99 Sweeper    1
```

and you could do the query by "order by FLAG"